# get all the paths of files inside a directory python

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve all the files in a folder with a specific extension. But the problem is that I dont know how many sub-directories can be in there..

So basically something like:

```
                   ------ filex.py
       ---folder1               -------- filezs.py
root             ------- folder2
       --- file.py              ----- fileabc.py
       --- file.txt
```

and so on

So basically I want to write a function which does the following:

```
 def get_files(root,files_of_type):
  return dict{key = file_name: value = path}
```

So for example if I want to get all the file and their path of extension py

then this will be like:

```
  root = "/path/to/root"
  files_of_type = [".py"]

 returns  {"filex.py": "/path/to/root/folder1".. and so on}
```

Any suggestions
Thanks

Comment: You have two questions: 1) How do I get a listing of files recursively, and 2) how do I filter out files based on extension. If you search, you can find both of these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk). For each level of directory it will give you the directory path, a list of any subdirectory names, and a list of any file names in that directory. From there you can assemble the dictionary to return.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def get_files(root, files_of_type):
    rv = {}

    for cwd, folders, files in os.walk(root):
        for fname in files:
            # os.path.splitext splits a filename into a tuple like so:
            # (file_path, extension)
            if os.path.splitext(fname)[1] in files_of_type:
                # key = filename, value = directory of file
                rv[fname] = cwd 

    return rv
```